# Using Hector Slam, do you need odom?

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to improve my robot, currently its very simple and has a Lidar (Neato) that works out where it is.  No odom from the motors is published

Would publishing odom the motors improve my navigation results?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257445/using-hector-slam,-do-you-need-odom?/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hector Slam do not need odom

---

Originally posted by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) with karma: 188 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0